# How do I 'lookup' a Redis value shoved into Redis by Spring's RedisTemplate with the redis-clI?

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data-redis

I have some Java code implemented in Spring that persists a Java Bean like...

```
@Repository
public class SomeDamnRedisRepository {
  private static final String KEY = "someDamn";
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeDamnRedisRepository.class);
  ...
  private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;
  private HashOperations hashOps;

  @Autowired
  public SomeDamnRedisRepository(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    hashOps = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
  }

  public void save(SomeDamn someDamn) {
    try {
      hashOps.put(KEY, someDamn.getVersion(), someDamn);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.warn(String.format("ignoring exception on save(%s)", someDamn != null ? someDamn.getVersion() : "null"), e);
    }
  }

  public SomeDamn get(String version) {
    try {
      return (SomeDamn) hashOps.get(KEY, version);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.warn(String.format("ignoring exception on get(%s)", version), e);
    }
    return null;

  }
}
```

The SomeDamn Java Bean is simple enough (Lombok is maintain Java bean).

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SomeDamn implements Serializable {
  private String id;           // This guy like "1"
  private String displayValue; // This guy like "One"
  private String version;      // This guy like "urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792"
}
```

In the redis-cli I get to see that *something* mutilated my "key desire" (I expected just "someDamn).

```
$ redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
1) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bsomeDamn"
```

What is the redis-cli invocation to get it to return the value stored on "someDamn" key for the URN "urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792". Like if I stored `new SomeDamn("1", "one", "urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792");`?

Up-the-middle GET on what the cli reports on the key doesn't do anything

```
127.0.0.1:6379> GET \xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bsomeDamn
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> GET someDamn
(nil)
```

Is there a "dump all the values at KEY 'someDamn' or something I can use to reason this out?

Redis is like a roach motel for me right now; bugs go in. Nothing comes out.

How do I find the value "urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792" on the redis key "someDamn" through the redis-cli for something put there by up-the-middle Spring Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using HASHSET in Redis, so you have to use

`HGETALL key`

`HGET key field`

As i can see from code -  your key is `someDamn` and field is `urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792`

Official documentation also contains some examples if you will need them
https://redis.io/commands/hget/

Comment: THanks. I can get there from here. 

What my eyes should be "someDamn" and "urn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792" is actually...`HGETALL "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bsomeDamn"` and `HGET "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x0bsomeDamn" "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00Eurn:com.example.object-ref:version:2f7dcb42-a27d-4c9f-88d4-8721b3642792"`. That "\xacblahblah" thing is called a prefix in Redis?

Comment: No, its because you haven't configured hash key serialiser for your redis template.

paste something like this where you configure RedisTemplate

`template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());`

Comment: pretty much the same question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55967558/spring-data-redis-hash-keys-with-weird-prefixes-and-hscan-not-returning-resul

Comment: You should try using the RedisInsight tool to get a browsable view of what's in your Redis instance.  It also has a built in command line if you want to drop down to entering the raw commands.   It's free. https://redis.com/redis-enterprise/redis-insight/

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve a Hash by key use
`HGETALL <mykey>`, retrieves the whole hash, if you just want a certain name-value pair from the hash, then do `HGET <mykey> <myname>` and you get a single value back.